# What are some design communities that I can share my articles with?

Tags: ux-field, community

I started writing some stories on Medium and I wanted to share my work with the world, and people who are interested in design. Where do I find communities that would welcome this without me feeling left out or irrelevant? I mean posting my articles here feels not professional at all. I tried LinkedIn and it seems like its working but I feel like there's more.

**I hope if somebody can help me out by introducing me to some design communities that I might not know yet.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the UX publications on Medium, like [UX Collective](https://uxdesign.cc/why-and-how-to-publish-with-the-ux-collective-8c8d1dd018a7), [UX Planet](https://uxplanet.org/how-to-publish-your-content-on-ux-planet-fd9dc99756db) and others. Also other non-Medium publications might be a good fit - if you just google for design-related blogs you'll find a bunch.

Comment: Awesome, thank a lot!